# $test->lol = "kek" VS $test['lol'] = "kek"; что лучше

Tags: php, массивы, laravel

Какую конструкцию лучше использовать, strObj или переменную?

В форке Laravel везде встречаю конструкцию `$массив->переменная = "значение";`

сам всегда использовал `$массив['переменная'] = "значение";`

Что лучше, что правильней и почему?

Comment: `в форке Laravel везде встречаю конструкцию $массив->переменная = "значение";` - можете показать, конкретно где вы видели такую запись?

Comment: [Скриншот , участка взятого от балды](http://joxi.ru/L21LqGxS8MNdlm.jpg)

Comment: и где на том скрине именно массив? Или в вашем понимании массив, это всё что пишется `$что-то->что-то` ??

Comment: `$массив->переменная` и `$массив['переменная']` это разные вещи в PHP . Вот в JS одинаковые, а в PHP они одинаковые только для http://php.net/manual/ru/class.arrayobject.php

Comment: я самоучка , многого не знаю , и говорю так как я это себе представляю с технической точки зрения , так что не судите меня строго ) , спасибо за предоставленную информацию

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оператор `->` обозначает обращение к полю или методу объекта, а не к элементу массива.
То есть выражение `$object->var = "abc";` означает присвоить переменной **var** объекта **$object** определенное значение.

А запись `$array['key'] = 'abc'` присваивает ассоциативному массиву **$array** значение, доступное по ключу **key**.